How do VS Code extensions automate distribution across different platform architectures?
I'm relatively new to VS Code extension development and understand that VS Code extensions do not natively support distributing different extension packages based on the architecture (like win-x86, darwin-arm64, etc.).
How do projects that involve non-cross-platform packages handle automatic distribution? For instance, how is this implemented in the rust-analyzer project? I've gone through the code at rust-analyzer on GitHub but couldn't find relevant details. Can anyone familiar with this help clarify?

Not sure how you read the code, but clearly the publishing steps are in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/blob/2024-06-11/.github/workflows/release.yaml#L105

I noticed the series of rust-analyzer-${platform}-${arch}.vsix files under the Assets section on the rust-analyzer releases page. However, I believe these are meant for manual installation, correct?
Regarding the VSCode extension marketplace, each project appears to be limited to uploading a single VSIX file. Additionally, I didn't see multiple, platform-specific rust-analyzer packages on the VSCode marketplace. This suggests that the distribution and fetching of multiple LSP packages across platforms are likely handled internally within the package itself. Yet, I haven't found the code

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#platformspecific-extensions vsce supports publishing platform specific bits.

thank you very much ! I was misled by outdated documentation and the GUI console of the extension marketplace, which led me down the wrong path initially !
